# Как перевернуть таблицу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, pivot

Есть таблица из .xlsx вида:

```
Вопрос
ответ
ответ
ответ
ответ
Вопрос
ответ
ответ
ответ
ответ
```

---

Количество ответов всегда 4

Нужно привести к следующему виду:

```
Вопрос1 | ответ1 | ответ2 | ответ3 | ответ4
Вопрос2 | ответ1 | ответ2 | ответ3 | ответ4
```

Есть ли простой вариант всё это перевернуть?
Все мои идеи подразумевают введение доп.столбца с индексами 0..4 итд

Comment: можете выложить ваш Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Весь файл очень большой, ссылка на идентичный пример: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X-rTzOohZ2vKym0Wnl9sXse7v0vsr36h/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\пример.xlsx", header=None, names=["val"])
df["idx"] = np.arange(0, len(df)) // 5
df.loc[np.arange(0, len(df), 5), "Type"] = "Вопрос"
df.loc[df["Type"].isna(), "Type"] = \
    "Ответ" + (df.loc[df["Type"].isna()].groupby("idx").cumcount()+1).astype(str)
res = (df.pivot(index="idx", columns="Type", values="val")
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

результат:

```
In [106]: res
Out[106]:
                                    Вопрос  Ответ1 Ответ2 Ответ3   Ответ4
0           В каком году случилось что-то?    1980   1998   1975     1906
1     Сколько атомов у такого-то элемента?       2      3      4        5
2   В каком городе не работал великий к...  Берлин  Париж    Рим  Неаполь
```